# C# WPF MediaElement.Volume resets when changing computer's playback device

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mediaelement

I'm playing videos with .NET WPF's MediaElement and want the video to play on mute so I set the volume to 0. Simple enough.

The problem is, when I right-click on the system's audio icon and select "Playback devices" and change the default playback device, the MediaElement's volume gets reset.

I don't know of any way to detect such a change in the system's configuration, so how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using the MediaElement's IsMuted property to set the volume?

Comment: I hadn't seen that property, but setting IsMuted still leaves the same problem. When switching audio device, this gets reset as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to get rid of this with a binding. You'll need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged somewhere - I'm using the MVVM Light framework here, which uses RaisePropertyChanged.

XAML:

```
<MediaElement IsMuted="{Binding IsMuted}" />
```

Codebehind/ViewModel:

```
/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="IsMuted" /> property's name.
/// </summary>
public const string IsMutedPropertyName = "IsMuted";

private bool _isMuted = true;

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the IsMuted property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
/// </summary>
public bool IsMuted
{
    get
    {
        return _isMuted;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_isMuted == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        //IsMuted will always return true
        _isMuted = true;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsMuted");
    }
}
```

Be careful with this and give it some thorough testing. I'm not 100% sure I could guarantee that it'll pull the level back to 0 before you get a sample or two playing back as a very brief squawk.